# Access Wordpress Core Functions in a Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress plugin that gives a print view of page using query string and i have a code like this in my plugin:

```
if(isset($_GET['print']) && $_GET['print'] == "true") {

    // some code

    exit();
}
```

But I got some error about wordpress functions like the_post() and etc.
First I wanna know am i doing the right way to show a print version of pages?
Second if i am doing right, how should I include wordpress core functions?
(I think I show include wp-load.php somehow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All WordPress functions are available in a plugin. The matter is hooking in the right place.

Simple example:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Test Plugin 
 */

// This hook is fired once WP, all plugins, and the theme are fully loaded and instantiated
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'plugin_so_18538270' );

function plugin_so_18538270()
{
    // Admin area, do nothing
    if( is_admin() )
        return;

    // "true" == $var
    // See Yoda Conditions: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html
    if( isset( $_GET['print'] ) && "true" == $_GET['print'] ) 
    {
        // some code
        exit();
    }
}
```

References:

- [Writing_a_Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and [Plugin_API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) at the Codex.
- Highest voted Questions in the [<Plugin-Development>](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development?sort=votes&pagesize=50) tag at WordPress Answers.